# How to get subscription level id from url for the Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to adjust one message which depend on some conditions. Currently It's already on the logic for the login/not login user ..

```
<?php if(is_user_logged_in()) : ?>
<h1 class="abo-title page-title abo-payment"><?php echo __( 'Zahlungsdetails',     'issuem-leaky-paywall' ); ?></h1>
    <p>Bitte geben Sie Ihre Zahlungsdetails ein.</p>
    <?php else: ?>
    <h1 class="abo-title page-title abo-register"><?php echo __( 'Registrieren  Sie sich hier für Ihren Gratismonat.', 'issuem-leaky-paywall' ); ?><br><span class="bold"><?php echo __( 'Keine Verpflichtung, jederzeit kündbar.', 'issuem-leaky-paywall' ) ?></span></h1>
    <?php endif ?
```

But now I need to show another message for the not login users but who will come to the subscribe page directly with the subscribe level id on the URL such as ...

```
https://example.de/subscribe/
```

and it has three or more options to click for the paid subscriptions such as ....

```
https://example.de/register/?level_id=1
https://example.de/register/?level_id=2
.....
```

according to the level id I have to change the messages.

It's Wordpress site and I tried to get the level id to show the different messages. And it has leaky-paywall plugin.

any ideas ?

Comment: its subscriber or user id

Comment: Not login or new visitors who are going to subscribe as a subscriber  with the given  link as described

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `GET` to check if your url contains `level_id` or not. Like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['level_id'])){
$level_id = trim($_GET['level_id']);
}else{
$level_id = false;
}

<?php if(is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
<h1 class="abo-title page-title abo-payment"><?php echo __( 'Zahlungsdetails',     'issuem-leaky-paywall' ); ?></h1>
    <p>Bitte geben Sie Ihre Zahlungsdetails ein.</p>
    <?php else: ?>
    <h1 class="abo-title page-title abo-register"><?php echo __( 'Registrieren  Sie sich hier für Ihren Gratismonat.', 'issuem-leaky-paywall' ); ?><br><span class="bold"><?php echo __( 'Keine Verpflichtung, jederzeit kündbar.', 'issuem-leaky-paywall' ) ?></span></h1>

    <?php } elseif($level_id == 1){ ?>

         // Your custom message for level_id 1

   <?php } elseif($level_id == 2){ ?>

      // Your custom message for level_id 2

     <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: You are asking for subscriber role id.

**Note : insecure way to pass please use hidden field for this.**

`get_users($args)` it  allows you get list of subscriber user.

```
<?php
$args = array(
 'role' => 'subscriber',
 'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
 'order' => 'ASC'
);
 $subscribers = get_users($args);
echo '<ul>';
 foreach ($subscribers as $user) {
 echo '<li>' . $user->display_name.'['.$user->user_email . ']</li>';
 }
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Case 2: You want to redirect before register to attached URL.

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_registration_url(); ?>">Register</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Vasim, actually the users are not login and I have to get the level id from the URL to show the message. They don't have data in DB since there are going to subscribe.

Comment: without login its never a user it guest user

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Yeah guest users ( I mentioned above as new visitors on your first comment)

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-creating-redirects-in-wordpress/ please usr this

Comment: I don't want to redirect , I just need to get the level id from the URL to show different messages depend on the level ID and the level id will show on the url according to the click of the subscribe options. Hope it makes more clear. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130956/discussion-between-moyen-uddin-and-vasim-vanzara).